# Copy PoseBone rotation between two bones into a new armature with a different bone hierarchy

Tags: python, pose-mode

I have two armatures:

[image]

In pose mode, I would like to copy the rotation between Bone.001 and Bone.002 on the left armature (yellow circle) and apply it to the connected bones Bone.001 and Bone.002 on the right armature (green circle).

I have tried to calculate this using rotation_difference:

```
source_bone_001_rot = source_bone_001.matrix.to_3x3().col[1]
source_bone_002_rot = source_bone_002.matrix.to_3x3().col[1]
rotation = source_bone_001_rot.rotation_difference(source_bone_002_rot)
```

and then tried applying this rotation difference to the target bone (Bone.002):

```
target_bone002_matrix = target_bone_002.matrix.copy()
loc, rot, sca = target_bone002_matrix.decompose()

newmatrix = rotation.to_matrix()
newmatrix.resize_4x4()
newmatrix[0][3] = loc.x
newmatrix[1][3] = loc.y
newmatrix[2][3] = loc.z

target_bone_002.matrix = newmatrix
```

I could see the rotations getting close, but not exact. I'm new to Blender scripting.